# What type of fish is this and why is it so big?

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

[image]

This is a screenshot from a youtube video that you can watch here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcdJNPYkIE0

Comment: Some sort of [grouper?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=grouper&client=safari&hl=en-gb&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYz6XJ_aHVAhXkK8AKHVJFD88Q_AUICSgB&biw=375&bih=559&dpr=3)

Comment: I think it's the pacific goliath grouper

Comment: Yeah but its a whale. this is a "fish" from the title so I didnt assume it to be huge

Comment: White Shark? Whale Shark? Tuna? There are lots of large fish species...

Comment: I'm simply going off the name of it. When someone mentions "fish" you don't really imagine the really big ones. Fish you usually imagine small. Whereas if someone mentions "shark or whale", then obviously you have a different idea on size.

Comment: Whales are mammals, not fishes - calling a large fish a whale is just wrong (and of course the confusingly named whale shark is not a whale at all). Sharks are fishes, but they are a separate category of fishes from the rest. There are both large and small sharks. The smallest ones are only ~20cm, which probably makes them smaller than what you typically think of when you think of "fish".

Comment: Why is it so big? Because it’s parents were. It’s called heredity.

Comment: @KSplitX have a look at the [mola mola](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZCJfIg0RBo), [tuna](http://mrc.virginia.gov/vswft/State_Records/state-record-bluefin_tuna_040615.shtm), [sturgeon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ak2ci1XkxU0), [catfish](https://www.connexionfrance.com/French-news/World-record-catch-in-the-Tarn), and the largest fish species in the world, [*Rhincodon typus*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8IJFJDrY2CY) for examples of BIG fish!

Answer (score -1):

That is a Queensland Grouper (common name).

Comment: to be a proper answer you need to include how you determined this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! When you reach 50 reputation points you can leave comments on other people's posts. There's a fairly high bar for posting answers, and as the other comment mentions, adding supporting sources is always a good idea and almost always necessary here. Don't worry about the negative voting so much, but if you can explain what it is that leads you to this conclusion, that would be better.